# Discord.js doesn't create temporary channels

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot which will create temporary voice channles

Code:

```
var temporary = []

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const mainCatagory = '677192265491415041';
    const mainChannel = '677875869351542803';
    if (newMember.voiceChannelID == mainChannel) {
        newMember.guild.createChannel(`${newMember.user.username} 5vs5`, { type: 'voice', parent: mainCatagory })
            .then(async channel => {

                temporary.push({ newID: channel.id, guild: channel.guild })
                // A new element has been added to temporary array!
                await newMember.setVoiceChannel(channel.id)
            })
    }
    if (temporary.length >= 0) for (let i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++) {
        // Finding...
        let ch = temporary[i].guild.channels.find(x => x.id == temporary[i].newID)
        // Channel Found!         
        ch.setUserLimit(5)
        if (ch.members.size <= 0) {
            ch.delete(1000)
            // Channel has been deleted!
            return temporary.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }
})
```

Why it doesn't work?
it worked fine before i reinstalled system
node: 13.10.1
Win: 10

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly `does not work`. Provide some more information about what the problem is, if you get any errors and what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are having issues with asynchronous code.  You have the following line:

`await newMember.setVoiceChannel(channel.id)`

That is not getting awaited as you are expecting it to because it falls within the block of a `.then`.  The await only affects the code in that async block in the `.then` statement, and since nothing occurs after that line, it's not functionally doing anything different than it would if you didn't await it.

You should try to avoid mixing .then and async/await if possible (there are reasons you might mix but you need to know what you are doing).  In this case I suggest setting the entire event handler to be async and await both.

Note: The following assumes you are using discord.js v11, which is consistent with your earlier code sample.  If you are using v12 you should be using `guild.channels.create()`, `guild.channels.cache.find()`, and `newMember.voice.setChannel()` instead.  You said you just installed a new instance of node and presumable discord.js so you may in fact be on v12 now and that could be part of your issue.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const mainCatagory = '677192265491415041';
    const mainChannel = '677875869351542803';
    if (newMember.voiceChannelID == mainChannel) {
        let channel = await newMember.guild.createChannel(`${newMember.user.username} 5vs5`, { type: 'voice', parent: mainCatagory })

        temporary.push({ newID: channel.id, guild: channel.guild })
        // A new element has been added to temporary array!
        await newMember.setVoiceChannel(channel.id)
    }
    // The rest of your code.
}
```